# How to disable checkbox after check checkbox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

created two checkboxes.If any one checkbox is checked another one is automatically goes to disable mode and if it is unchecked it comes to normal mode.
But my code is not working in some cases .

```
<div>                  
    <label>First checkbox</label>
    <input class="myCheckbox classA" data-target="maindiv1" type="checkbox" name="first" id="first_box"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label>Second checkbox</label>
    <input class="myCheckbox classB" data-target="maindiv2" type="checkbox" name="second" id="second_box"/>
</div>
```

script code here

```
$(document).on('click', '.classA', function (e) {
    if ($('.classA:checked').length) {
        $('.classB').prop('disabled', true);
        $('.classB').prop('checked', false);
        return;
    }
    $('.classB').prop('disabled', false);
});

$(document).on('click', '.classB', function (e) {
    if ($('.classB:checked').length) {
        $('.classA').prop('disabled', true);
        $('.classA').prop('checked', false);
        return;
    }
    $('.classA').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example of your code, where we can see the error?

Comment: What's wrong with using radio buttons? That's said, a radio button couldn't be unchecked but maybe you should rethink your UI

Comment: You should consider radio buttons

Comment: Looks more like cascading checkboxes than radio buttons (as the other is also disabled).

Comment: in which cases its failing?

Comment: Tried it and looks fine, not sure in which case it's failing

Comment: Don't use `click` on a checkbox, use `changed`

Comment: I have two html pages  first page having this two check boxes. Second page having another data.First i'm in first page i checked any one check box after i go to second page and come back to first page i'm unchecked the check box this check box is unchecked but another one disabled.This is my guessed scenario.For example i'm in only first page it is working fine but once go to another page and come back to first page it is not working.